# Can't "save as" or copy a C# project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I want to copy a C# project so I can make some changes to it while keeping the old one.

When I copy its whole folder, the solution file does not open on Visual Studio 2008. Visual Studio starts and it does not open anything.

Comment: `"so I can make some changes to it while keeping the old one"` - You might want to look into using source control.  Git, for example.  It's *great* at keeping copies of ongoing changes to code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no "built-in" tool for this.

In **Solution Explorer**, *Right-Click* your solution and select "Open Folder in Windows Explorer":

[image: screenshot Open Folder in Windows Explorer]

In *Windows Explorer*, select one folder up:

[image: screenshot one folder up]

*Right-Click* your Project's folder, then Copy it to the Clipboard:

[image: screenshot copy folder]

Now, simply **Paste** your Clipboard contents in the same directory or in another directory.

**NOTE:** If your project uses relative path names and you paste your project into a different directory, you will need to go in and fix any broken link references.

Answer (score 1):

If you are opening the solution file, you will need to open the solution explorer pane in Visual Studio and then select the project/file you want to open.

Answer (score 0):

Do you right click the folder, select copy, and then paste the copy? You can copy the whole folder and simply rename the folder to something else. There shouldn't be any problems with that. I have done this many times and always was able to open the copy.

Visual Studio 2013 Express is free and out right now. Try it if everything else fails.